# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java

I am trying to run a program found here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/UnsharpMaskDemo.htm
I simply created an Eclipse project for it an pasted it into a new class. The program code assumes that you have a picture file located somewhere

```
private void loadImage() {
    try {
        this.image = GraphicsUtilities.loadCompatibleImage(getClass().
                getResource("A.jpg"));
        this.image = GraphicsUtilities.createThumbnail(this.image, 300);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I edit this to a file placed in the src folder. Strangely, the Exception above is not thrown and caught, regardsless of what path I provide. Instead i get an exception from a method somewhere later in the code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at GraphicsUtilities.loadCompatibleImage(UnsharpMaskDemo.java:563)
    at UnsharpMaskDemo.loadImage(UnsharpMaskDemo.java:216)
    at UnsharpMaskDemo.<init>(UnsharpMaskDemo.java:99)
    at UnsharpMaskDemo$5.run(UnsharpMaskDemo.java:229)
```

No matter where I place the image or write the path, I get this. What am I doing wrong? I assume the program is well tested and would work out of the box...

Comment: Have you verified that the `getClass().getResource("A.jpg")` returns the same path that you put `A.jpg` in?

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work if I place it in the bin folder, where the .class files lie compiled. But it does bother me that no other paths worked.

Comment: Native how do I verify that?

Comment: @user1507316 Did you try relative pathes either (the base is your 'bin' folder)?

Comment: Try 
`URL url=getClass().getResources("/getresources/test.txt");`
`String path=url.toString();`
`File f=new File(path);`
`System.out.println(f.getAbsoulutePath());`
to see if the path is the same as the one in you filesystem

Comment: @user1507316 no I can't get it to accept relative paths, strange.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResource("A.jpg")` tells the JVM to look for the file `A.jpg` somwhere on the classpath of the current class's classloader.

This explains why it works when putting it in the `bin` folder since this is on eclipse's classpath by default. You might also put it in your source-folder since then eclipse should copy it to the `bin`-folder while building.

To use another folder you can rightclick your eclipse-project, select `Build Path` -> `Configure Build Path`and on the `Libraries`-tab use `Add Class Folder` or `Add External Class Folder` to add the folder containing the image to the project's classpath.